# C++ insertion sort implementation

Tags: c++, sorting, c++17, insertion-sort

I was wondering if this implementation of insertion sort could be improved. Are there any things that I have done wrong?

```
template<typename Element>
void insertion_sort(Element arr[], size_t size) {
    size_t index, index_sorted;
    for (index = 0u; index < size; ++index) {
        auto temp = arr[index];
        index_sorted = index - 1;
        while (arr[index_sorted] >= 0 && arr[index_sorted] > temp) {
            arr[index_sorted + 1] = arr[index_sorted--];
        }
        arr[index_sorted + 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using C++17? If yes, please add the c++17 tag. If not, the line `arr[index_sorted  + 1] = arr[index_sorted--];` is undefined behavior. [More info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Small nitpicks

- The for loop can be started from 1, as the iteration with 0 doesn't actually do anything.
- Prefer to reduce the scope of variables if possible. This allows better reasoning for the compiler/optimizer, and makes the code more readable because the variable declaration is nearer to the actual usage.
- The check `arr[index_sorted] >= 0` in the while loop should probably be `index_sorted >= 0u` (after all, `Element` might not be comparable to integers), but this is `true` in all cases (`-1` for an unsigned integer type is equal to that type's maximum value). However, even checking this becomes unnecessary if the first iteration starts at 1.
- The array elements could possibly be moved to their new locations (this might improve performance in some cases).

```
template<typename Element>
void insertion_sort(Element arr[], size_t size) {
    for (auto index = 1u; index < size; ++index) {
        auto temp = std::move(arr[index]);
        auto index_sorted = index - 1;
        while (arr[index_sorted] > temp) {
            arr[index_sorted + 1] = std::move(arr[index_sorted--]);
        }
        arr[index_sorted + 1] = std::move(temp);
    }
}
```

> Technically, the size of the array could be deduced automatically by taking a reference (though it has an ugly syntax). However, by taking an explicit size parameter one can sort a partial array, so I'd prefer the flexibility of this approach.